# Excel writer date format error

Tags: date, metadata, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have a source data(.csv) with a Date column which a format 
 "dd/mm/yyyy" and when I try to output this date column into Excel writer, it gives me an error and also Excel writer step doesn't has the same format built-in  in the content tab-->fields-->Type of this step. I even tried using select values step and specified the metadata of date format as "dd/mm/yyyy".

Transformation:

[image]

Drop-down date format list from Microsoft Excel Writer step:

[image: Date formats]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft Excel Writer` does support `Date` type with `dd/MM/yyyy` format which is properly saved in a cell within a created file. I suggest you don't choose the option from drop-down, as it may not be full, but rather type it by hand.

Here's an example I've run which proves it:

[image: Sample]

As an additional note it's good to remember, that if you ever face such issues and find that even though you can ensure formatting of a column in previous steps in the step where it can't be enforced you could go for `String` type with `#` format - this would treat the input column value as-is and thus not altering it in any way that it came from the previous step.

Comment: your second suggestion of making the datatype of date as String in Microsoft Excel Writer worked! This is really a good idea to do so ,Thanks